# Circles stick to things in game engine

Tags: java, collision-detection, game-physics

In the physics ([written following this tutorial](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331)) part of my game engine ([on github](https://github.com/kyranstar/GameLib)), sometimes collisions between AABBs and circles or between circles and circles stick together, like so (apologies for the gif artifacts):

[image]

I've confirmed that this happens even when I don't call `applyFriction`, so it's not that. I've also made the `positionalCorrection` algorithm uses 1.05f for `percent`, but even that doesn't fix anything, so I'm stumped.

```
public final class Collisions {
    private Collisions() {
        // cant instantiate this class
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether two GameObjects are colliding
     *
     * @param a
     *            must be a RectObject or CircleObject
     * @param b
     *            must be a RectObject or CircleObject
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isColliding(final GameEntity a, final GameEntity b) {
        final CShape as = a.shape;
        final CShape bs = b.shape;

        if (as instanceof RectShape && bs instanceof RectShape) {
            return isColliding((RectShape) as, (RectShape) bs);
        }
        if (as instanceof CircleShape && bs instanceof CircleShape) {
            return isColliding((CircleShape) as, (CircleShape) bs);
        }
        if (as instanceof RectShape && bs instanceof CircleShape) {
            return isColliding((RectShape) as, (CircleShape) bs);
        }
        if (as instanceof CircleShape && bs instanceof RectShape) {
            return isColliding((RectShape) bs, (CircleShape) as);
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private static boolean isColliding(final RectShape a, final RectShape b) {
        return collisionNormal(a, b) != null;
    }

    private static boolean isColliding(final CircleShape o1, final CircleShape o2) {
        final float c = o1.radius + o2.radius;
        final float b = o1.center.x - o2.center.x;
        final float a = o1.center.y - o2.center.y;

        return c * c > b * b + a * a;
    }

    private static boolean isColliding(final RectShape a, final CircleShape b) {
        final float circleDistance_x = Math.abs(b.center().x - (a.min.x + a.width() / 2));
        final float circleDistance_y = Math.abs(b.center().y - (a.min.y + a.height() / 2));

        if (circleDistance_x > a.width() / 2 + b.radius) {
            return false;
        }
        if (circleDistance_y > a.height() / 2 + b.radius) {
            return false;
        }

        if (circleDistance_x <= a.width() / 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (circleDistance_y <= a.height() / 2) {
            return true;
        }

        final int cornerDistance_sq = (int) Math.pow(circleDistance_x - a.width() / 2, 2) + (int) Math.pow(circleDistance_y - a.height() / 2, 2);

        return cornerDistance_sq <= (int) Math.pow(b.radius, 2);

    }

    /**
     * Returns the face normal of a collision between a and b
     *
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @return null if no collision
     */
    private static Vec2D collisionNormal(final RectShape a, final RectShape b) {
        final float w = 0.5f * (a.width() + b.width());
        final float h = 0.5f * (a.height() + b.height());
        final float dx = a.center().x - b.center().x;
        final float dy = a.center().y - b.center().y;

        if (Math.abs(dx) <= w && Math.abs(dy) <= h) {
            /* collision! */
            final float wy = w * dy;
            final float hx = h * dx;

            if (wy > hx) {
                if (wy > -hx) {
                    /* collision at the top */
                    return new Vec2D(0, -1);
                } else {
                    /* on the left */
                    return new Vec2D(1, 0);
                }
            } else {
                if (wy > -hx) {
                    /* on the right */
                    return new Vec2D(-1, 0);
                } else {
                    /* at the bottom */
                    return new Vec2D(0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void fixCollision(final GameEntity a, final GameEntity b) {
        fixCollision(generateManifold(a, b), true);
    }

    /**
     * Fixes a collision between two objects by correcting their positions and applying impulses.
     *
     */
    public static void fixCollision(final CManifold m, final boolean applyFriction) {
        final GameEntity a = m.a;
        final GameEntity b = m.b;

        // Calculate relative velocity
        final Vec2D rv = b.velocity.minus(a.velocity);

        // Calculate relative velocity in terms of the normal direction
        final float velAlongNormal = rv.dotProduct(m.normal);

        // Calculate restitution
        final float e = Math.min(a.getRestitution(), b.getRestitution());

        // Calculate impulse scalar
        float j = -(1 + e) * velAlongNormal;
        j /= a.getInvMass() + b.getInvMass();

        // Apply impulse
        final Vec2D impulse = m.normal.multiply(j);

        a.velocity = a.velocity.minus(impulse.multiply(a.getInvMass()));
        b.velocity = b.velocity.plus(impulse.multiply(b.getInvMass()));

        if (applyFriction) {
            applyFriction(m, j);
        }

        positionalCorrection(m);
    }

    private static void applyFriction(final CManifold m, final float normalMagnitude) {
        final GameEntity a = m.a;
        final GameEntity b = m.b;

        // relative velocity
        final Vec2D rv = b.velocity.minus(a.velocity);
        // normalized tangent force
        final Vec2D tangent = rv.minus(m.normal.multiply(m.normal.dotProduct(rv))).unitVector();
        // friction magnitude
        final float jt = -rv.dotProduct(tangent) / (a.getInvMass() + b.getInvMass());

        // friction coefficient
        final float mu = (a.getStaticFriction() + b.getStaticFriction()) / 2;
        final float dynamicFriction = (a.getDynamicFriction() + b.getDynamicFriction()) / 2;

        // Coulomb's law: force of friction <= force along normal * mu
        final Vec2D frictionImpulse = Math.abs(jt) < normalMagnitude * mu ? tangent.multiply(jt) : tangent.multiply(-normalMagnitude
                * dynamicFriction);

        // apply friction
        a.velocity = a.velocity.minus(frictionImpulse.multiply(a.getInvMass()));
        b.velocity = b.velocity.plus(frictionImpulse.multiply(b.getInvMass()));
    }

    /**
     * Generates a collision manifold from two colliding objects.
     *
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @return
     */
    private static CManifold generateManifold(final GameEntity a, final GameEntity b) {
        final CManifold m = new CManifold();
        m.a = a;
        m.b = b;
        final CShape as = a.shape;
        final CShape bs = b.shape;

        if (as instanceof RectShape && bs instanceof RectShape) {
            return generateManifold((RectShape) as, (RectShape) bs, m);
        } else if (as instanceof CircleShape && bs instanceof CircleShape) {
            return generateManifold((CircleShape) as, (CircleShape) bs, m);
        } else if (as instanceof RectShape && bs instanceof CircleShape) {
            return generateManifold((RectShape) as, (CircleShape) bs, m);
        } else if (as instanceof CircleShape && bs instanceof RectShape) {
            m.b = a;
            m.a = b;
            return generateManifold((RectShape) bs, (CircleShape) as, m);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    private static CManifold generateManifold(final RectShape a, final RectShape b, final CManifold m) {

        final Rectangle2D r = a.getRect().createIntersection(b.getRect());

        m.normal = collisionNormal(a, b);
        // penetration is the min resolving distance
        m.penetration = (float) Math.min(r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
        return m;
    }

    private static CManifold generateManifold(final CircleShape a, final CircleShape b, final CManifold m) {
        // A to B
        final Vec2D n = b.center.minus(a.center);
        final float dist = n.length();

        if (dist == 0) {
            // circles are on the same position, choose random but consistent values
            m.normal = new Vec2D(0, 1);
            m.penetration = Math.min(a.radius, b.radius);
            return m;
        }
        // don't recalculate dist to normalize
        m.normal = n.divide(dist);
        m.penetration = b.radius + a.radius - dist;
        return m;
    }

    private static CManifold generateManifold(final RectShape a, final CircleShape b, final CManifold m) {
        // Vector from A to B
        final Vec2D n = b.center.minus(a.center());

        // Closest point on A to center of B
        Vec2D closest = n;

        // Calculate half extents along each axis
        final float x_extent = a.width() / 2;
        final float y_extent = a.height() / 2;

        // Clamp point to edges of the AABB
        closest = new Vec2D(clamp(closest.x, -x_extent, x_extent), clamp(closest.y, -y_extent, y_extent));

        boolean inside = false;

        // Circle is inside the AABB, so we need to clamp the circle's center
        // to the closest edge
        if (n.equals(closest)) {
            inside = true;
            // Find closest axis
            if (Math.abs(closest.x) > Math.abs(closest.y)) {
                // Clamp to closest extent
                closest = new Vec2D(closest.x > 0 ? x_extent : -x_extent, closest.y);
            }
            // y axis is shorter
            else {
                // Clamp to closest extent
                closest = new Vec2D(closest.x, closest.y > 0 ? y_extent : -y_extent);
            }
        }
        // closest point to center of the circle
        final Vec2D normal = n.minus(closest);
        final float d = normal.length();
        final float r = b.radius;
        // Collision normal needs to be flipped to point outside if circle was
        // inside the AABB
        m.normal = inside ? normal.unitVector().multiply(-1) : normal.unitVector();
        m.penetration = r - d;
        return m;
    }

    private static float clamp(final float n, final float lower, final float upper) {
        return Math.max(lower, Math.min(n, upper));
    }

    /**
     * Corrects positions between two colliding objects to avoid "sinking."
     *
     * @param m
     */
    private static void positionalCorrection(final CManifold m) {
        final GameEntity a = m.a;
        final GameEntity b = m.b;

        // the amount to correct by
        final float percent = 1f; // usually .2 to .8
        // the amount in which we don't really care, this avoids vibrating objects.
        final float slop = 0.05f; // usually 0.01 to 0.1

        final float correctionMag = m.penetration + (m.penetration > 0 ? -slop : slop);

        final Vec2D correction = m.normal.multiply(correctionMag / (a.getInvMass() + b.getInvMass()) * percent);
        a.moveRelative(correction.multiply(-1 * a.getInvMass()));
        b.moveRelative(correction.multiply(b.getInvMass()));
    }

}
```

**Update:**

I've fixed the problem so that circles don't stick to other circles anymore by making it so that I only check and fix between two objects once per tick (and not possible twice), but circles still sometimes stick to rectangles and can still ride underneath them.

Comment: Explanation from downvoter?

Comment: It is not clear what is your question, and how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Roman I'm not sure how to make it any more clear. Circles sometimes "stick" to other objects even when it should not happen in the real world. For example, the circles in the gif ride underneath the platform, when they should just fall off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I just had to change my calculations a bit in my `fixCollision` method.

[This is a link to the commit that fixed the problem, if you're curious.](https://github.com/kyranstar/GameLib/commit/005e53dfda631b595225971cbb633ac4ec06b5cf)